# Mathematically perfect way to get an evenly sampled "chain" of items

Tags: javascript, recursion, random

Say I want to create a list of numbers recursively by randomly picking a number from 0 to 9 to start and then (optionally) randomly picking another number between x+1 and 9, where x is the last number that was picked and optionally repeating this process. This way you can get lists like `1,3,6`, `3,4,8,9`, `2,7` and so on. This is a simplification of what I am really trying to do.

For my purposes I don't want to just pick a bunch of random numbers from list, remove duplicate and then sort them. This needs to be done recursively. The problem is that doing it plainly in the way I described will not give all numbers an equal chance. It will tend to pick larger numbers more than smaller ones. I tried something to counteract this but it then favours small numbers too much.

This is javascript using the random integer function from Lo-Dash:

```
function randomlist(index) {
    if (index > 8) return;
    var range = _.random(9 - index);
    var randex = [_.random(index, index + range)];
    if (_.random(10) < 6) randex = randex.concat(randomlist(randex[0] + 1));
    return randex
}

tally = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for (i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    var list = randomlist(0);
    list.forEach(function(x){tally[x]+=1});
}
```

Here, rather than just picking a random number between x and 9 and first pick a random smaller range and then pick a random number within that. I thought it might do the trick but when I run the above code, `tally` ends up looking like `[278, 262, 224, 189, 217, 180, 185, 179, 156, 61]`, clearly favouring smaller numbers. And if I adjust the chance of recursion then the balance shifts somewhat. I am hoping there may be some formula which allows for an adjustable chance of recursion and manages to produce lists that evenly sample all numbers.

Comment: Are you missing the fact that there are more large numbers than small ones, and that is why a random-number function tends to pick the large ones more often?  Perhaps you should think about all your range of numbers as having the same number of digits --the small ones simply begin with 0, like 053  and 008.

Comment: Why not pick the distances between the numbers and then compute the numbers with a scan? By scan I mean that [2,4,1,5,2] becomes [2,6,7,12,14].

Comment: What is your probability distribution? Do you just want a uniformly sampled random subset of the first 10 numbers? Then at each recursive step either take the particular item or not.

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim, I don't think you understand my question, because your answer doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @DanD., that sounds like it would still end up picking larger numbers more often, plus there is an upper limit, so it would have to cut off before it got into the double digits, for example.

Comment: @osa, I don't get what you are saying either.

Comment: `_.random(9 - index)` with index equals 0 has the same chance to pick `1` or any other number. But overall `1` has less chance to appear because it can only appear in the first cell. So you should replace `_.random(9 - index)` with a function that gives more weight to `1` according to the maximum size of the array. You may find the exact weight to give to each number by asking on [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Volune, I was just thinking in that direction. And yeah, it is a just math question I suppose.

Comment: Expanding on what Volune said, maybe you should exchange `_.random`  for a poisson distribution with lambda=1. Though, I'm not sure this will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, there are only a limited number of "lists" that fit that description.  So, suppose you create an array holding all of them, and then simply randomly select something from the array?  Here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>test-page</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<!--

var lists, und, tmp, dv, pkd, i, q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z;

function begin()
{ lists=[];
  for(i=0,q=0; q<10; q++)
    for(r=q+1;r<10;r++)
    { lists[i++]=[q,r];
      for(s=r+1;s<10;s++)
      { lists[i++]=[q,r,s];
        for(t=s+1;t<10;t++)
        { lists[i++]=[q,r,s,t];
          for(u=t+1;u<10;u++)
          { lists[i++]=[q,r,s,t,u];
            for(v=u+1;v<10;v++)
            { lists[i++]=[q,r,s,t,u,v];
              for(w=v+1;w<10;w++)
              { lists[i++]=[q,r,s,t,u,v,w];
                for(x=w+1;x<10;x++)
                { lists[i++]=[q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x];
                  for(y=x+1;y<10;y++)
                  { lists[i++]=[q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y];
                    for(z=y+1;z<10;z++)
                      lists[i++]=[q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z];
    } } } } } } } }
  for(j=0; j<i; j++)
  { tmp=document.createElement("span");
    tmp.innerHTML=lists[j]+"<br />";
    document.body.appendChild(tmp);  
  }  
  tmp=document.createElement("span");
  tmp.innerHTML="<br />Total: " + i + " lists. <br />";  //1013
  document.body.appendChild(tmp);
  pkd=[];
  i=0;  
  dv=document.getElementById("pks");
  return;
}

function Pick()
{ if(lists==und)
    return;
  q=Math.floor(Math.random()*1013);
  for(r=0; r<i; r++)
    if(pkd[r]==q)  //check this array for previously-picked list
      break;
  if(r==i)         //not previously picked?
  { pkd[i++]=q;    //add to array
    tmp=document.createElement("span");
    tmp.innerHTML=lists[q]+"<br />";
    dv.appendChild(tmp);  //display this list
  }
  else
    Pick();  //try again to pick an unpicked list
    //DON'T click the button more than 1013 times!
  return;
}

 // -->
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="create lists" onclick="begin();" />&nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="button" value="random pick" onclick="Pick();" /><br />
<br />
<div id="pks">
</div>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clever, and of course it produces a perfectly even sampling. The only problem is that it tends to produce too many long lists. In my description I mentioned that there is an (adjustable) percentage chance for each new number to be added to the list ever time it recurses. So if the probability is 50%, then you would get half as many 2-number lists as 1-number and one quarter as many 3-number lists and so on.

Comment: But actually I realized a solution that is similar to what you came up with. That is, I can produce a sorted list at the beginning of the recursive process and then pop elements off the list at each recursion. Because I do need the recursion, but these numbers don't actually have to be generated mid-recursion. But I didn't realize that when I asked the question.